# Ctrl + W not working

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I cannot close tabs in Chrome/Ffirefox/gedit using the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcuts work fine.

I checked *Gnome-tweak-tool → Theme → Keybinding* theme and it is set to default (not Emacs).

Comment: Facing this issue after: `sudo do-release-upgrade`